# PhantomJS ReferenceError for included function

Tags: javascript, jquery, phantomjs, referenceerror

I am trying to render a page of a webapp of mine.

```
<html>
  <head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="includes.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      load_gantt(some, values);
    });
   </script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <div class="container"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

As you can see I include jQuery and a joined javascript file which includes all my libs and custom scripts. It is joined into a single file to make sure that the depending libs are ready when the custom code kicks in. Might not be pretty or ideal but that is not the problem here.

The problem is the script block where I call load_gantt(). The function is defined at the end of include.js (after all the libs) like this:

```
load_gantt = function(some, values){ /* CODE HERE */ };
```

load_gantt() does the actual rendering to div.container and is pretty important. When I try to render this file with PhantomJS now, I get this error:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: load_gantt
```

I also tried to remove the script-Block and use phantomJS's evaluate-function to run load_gantt() but it results in the same error. It seems that the scope of the acutal HTML page is different from the scope of the included js files. However, the strange thing is, that phantomjs does not complain about the jQuery part of the script block although the jquery lib gets included the same way...

Code is working perfectly in every browser by the way. No problems or errors...

Edit: fixed some minor syntax error

Comment: Is your `load_gantt` variable a global variable?. Or is it residing under some function scope in your `includes.js` ?

Comment: It is global. As I said, the code is working properly in the browser. I tried to attach it to `window` by using `window.load_gantt  = function ..` but that gave me another error.. `TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'window.load_gantt(...)'` - Edit: I tried to bind the gantt lib (it is a DHTMLX Gantt Chart) to `window` aswell but the error remains.

Comment: @Max Which PhantomJS version do you use? Please register to the `onConsoleMessage`, `onError`, `onResourceError`, `onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-1_phantomerrors-js)). Maybe there are errors.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer but a fix.. I registered the `onConsoleMessage`, `onError`, `onResourceError` and `onResourceTimeout` events and noticed and error which indicated that the function was not initialized properly.

I used

```
load_gantt = function(a = 'default_a', b = 'default_b'){ /* ... */};
```

but PhantomJS does not get along with this... It has to be without the default values. I don't know why but it works now.

```
load_gantt = function(a, b){ /* ... */};
```